# Returning an image from a Quick Look generator does nothing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, quicklook

I'm trying to make a Quick Look generator. My understanding is that you can provide `QLPreviewRequestSetDataRepresentation` any type of data that can be understood by Quick Look out-of-the-box. I'd like to provide image data (`kUTTypeImage`).

Here's the simplest thing I can get to fail: load an input image and then immediately return it to `QLPreviewRequestSetDataRepresentation`.

(Obviously, in my real application I would do some custom transformations to the image before returning it, but even this simplified example seems to fail.)

```
NSImage *inputImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:inputImageURL];
QLPreviewRequestSetDataRepresentation(preview,
                                      (__bridge CFDataRef)([inputImage TIFFRepresentation]),
                                      kUTTypeImage,
                                      nil);
```

This doesn't work, even though the documentation gives every indication that it should. The Quick Look generator just crashes and falls back to the default display.

I know the NSImage is being properly read from the Quick Look bundle.

I can set the data to HTML just fine, and even include the image as an attachment and render as HTML, but that's a hacky solution.

[I've uploaded the full generator file as a Gist here.](https://gist.github.com/wilg/2d7f3057345321db0202)

Comment: Have you tried setting the type to the UTI of the specific image format that you are providing? (in this case, TIFF)

Comment: Yep, I tried setting it to "public.tiff".

Comment: Could you attach the syslog, crash log, etc.?

Comment: I’m having the same issue, look at [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526385/why-does-qlpreviewrequestsetdatarepresentation-on-mavericks-return-error-cgima). My code used to work but isn’t working anymore, since Mavericks, I guess.